# Search Data in Multiple Table and Found Result in Multiple GridView .VB

Tags: vb.net

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient


Public Class search
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim strcon As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\Application\Abhi\Software\Software\Vansh.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
    Private Sub search_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        '  con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\Application\Abhi\Software\Software\Vansh.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
        conn = New SqlConnection(strcon)
        conn.Open()
        loaddata()
        ' txtsearch.Enabled = False
        ' txtsearch.Text = "Student Id is auto number"


    End Sub

    Public Sub loaddata()
        conn = New SqlConnection(strcon)
        conn.Open()
        Dim str As String = "Select * From Payment "
        da = New SqlDataAdapter(str, conn)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "Payment")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Payment")
        da.Dispose()
        conn.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        For Each txt In {txtmo, txtsearch}
            txt.Clear()
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)


    End Sub

    Private Sub btnhome_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnhome.Click
        Me.Hide()
        Dim rd As New Home_Page
        rd.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtsearch_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtsearch.TextChanged
        Try
            conn = New SqlConnection(strcon)
            conn.Open()
            If txtsearch.Text = " " Then
                loaddata()

            Else
                conn = New SqlConnection(strcon)
                conn.Open()
                Dim Str As String = "Select Date, Name, Amount from Payment where Name like '" + txtsearch.Text + "%'  "
                da = New SqlDataAdapter(Str, conn)
                Dim ds As New DataSet
                da.Fill(ds, "Payment")
                DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Payment")
                da.Dispose()
                conn.Close()


            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick

    End Sub

    Private Sub txtmo_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtmo.TextChanged
        Try
            conn = New SqlConnection(strcon)
            conn.Open()
            If txtsearch.Text = " " Then
                loaddata()

            Else
                conn = New SqlConnection(strcon)
                conn.Open()
                Dim Str As String = "Select Date, Name, Amount from Payment where Date like '" + txtmo.Text + "%'  "
                da = New SqlDataAdapter(Str, conn)
                Dim ds As New DataSet
                da.Fill(ds, "Payment")
                DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Payment")
                da.Dispose()
                conn.Close()


            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged
        Try
            conn = New SqlConnection(strcon)
            conn.Open()
            If txtsearch.Text = " " Then
                loaddata()

            Else
                conn = New SqlConnection(strcon)
                conn.Open()
                Dim Str As String = "Select Date, Name, Amount from Payment where Date like '" + DateTimePicker1.Text + "%'  "
                da = New SqlDataAdapter(Str, conn)
                Dim ds As New DataSet
                da.Fill(ds, "Payment")
                DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Payment")
                da.Dispose()
                conn.Close()


            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub DataGridView2_CellContentClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.CellContentClick

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: A title and a wad of code do not constitute a well-formed question.  The title should be a summary only.  The question itself should provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the SPECIFIC issue you want help with.  Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) at least.